# Time complexity of finding the minimum by dynamic programing

Tags: time-complexity, optimization, dynamic-programming, polynomial-time

How can I calculate the complexity of computing $MD(b)$, where $b=(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n)$?

$$MD(s) = \max(s)-\min(s) + \min(MD(s\setminus\{\max(s)\}), MD(s\setminus\{\min(s)\}))$$
where $s$ is a finite multi-set of numbers with base case
$$MD(\text{one element})=0.$$

Thoughts: I think the time complexity is $O(n^2) $ because we need linear time to calculate the maximum and minimum of each $s$ and we have to do that $n$ times
So, $n+ (n-1)+ (n-2) + \dots = O(n^2)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimization with dynamic programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/155361/minimization-with-dynamic-programming)

Comment: @PålGD this is also my question but this part wasn't answered

Comment: Yes, but it's the same question. Did you prove optimality of your algorithm?

Comment: Then it should be $s\setminus\{\max(s)\}$.

Comment: For completeness, you should also supply the value of $MD(\emptyset)$.

Comment: @JohnL.: er, how do you know that ? (IMO, your guess is arbitrary.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was writing an answer to [the previous question with more information by the same author](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/155361/minimization-with-dynamic-programming). Unfortunately, the author deleted that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the time complexity is not $O(n^2)$.

Assume all elements in the given $b$ are different. Then the number of different multi-sets that appear on the left-hand side of the recurrence relation you will compute is $\Omega(n^2)$. The average time to find the minimum or the maximum is $\Omega(n)$. Hence the time-complexity of the whole algorithm is $\Omega(n^3)$.

---

What you can do (and you did) is to sort $b$ first, which takes $O(n\log n)$ time. Then it takes $O(1)$ time to locate the minimum and the maximum.

There are $O(n^2)$ $MD(c)$'s that the algorithm will compute. More specifically, each sequence of consecutively ordered elements of $b$ will appear as $c$. Such an sequence is determined by the starting element and the ending element. There are $n(n+1)/2$ of them.

- Each base case of one-element sequence takes $O(1)$ to set up.
- Thanks to the recurrence relation and and caching, it also takes $O(1)$ time to compute and store each non-base entry.

It takes $O(n^2)$ time to compute all entries. Since the entry $MD(b)$ is the wanted, the time complexity is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: I get the $O(nlogn)$ for sorting but can you explain further how we end up with $O(n^2)$?

Comment: @Battle Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If done recursively by brute force, the computation follows the recurrence

$$T(n)=2n+2T(n-1),$$ assuming that the cost of a $\min$ or $\max$ is $n$.
The solution of this recurrence is exponential $O(2^n)$.

But if you look closer, you only apply the function $MD$ to $\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$ different subsets, namely those corresponding to all subsequences of the sorted sequence. So I assume that you can solve in time $O(n^2)$, after sorting and using memoization, or using a bottom-up procedure.